# Can someone help me understand what this error means in pdfminer's pdf2txt: AttributeError: 'PDFObjRef' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, pdfminer

I am using pdfminer's pdf2txt.py to extract text from different pdf's.  The algorithm works very well in a lot of scenarios, but I am getting this error and I'm not sure what I can do to get pdfminer to work.

AttributeError: 'PDFObjRef' object has no attribute 'decode'

I have run this same command on other documents and this is the only one I am getting this error on.

I am simply running this off of the command line, so there is no other code to show:

```
pdf2txt.py -t xml -F -1.0 test.pdf
```

This is the complete output from pdf2txt.py

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pdf2txt.py", line 116, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/usr/local/bin/pdf2txt.py", line 110, in main
    interpreter.process_page(page)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pdfminer2-20151206-py2.7.egg/pdfminer/pdfinterp.py", line 834, in process_page
    self.render_contents(page.resources, page.contents, ctm=ctm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pdfminer2-20151206-py2.7.egg/pdfminer/pdfinterp.py", line 844, in render_contents
    self.init_resources(resources)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pdfminer2-20151206-py2.7.egg/pdfminer/pdfinterp.py", line 350, in init_resources
    self.fontmap[fontid] = self.rsrcmgr.get_font(objid, spec)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pdfminer2-20151206-py2.7.egg/pdfminer/pdfinterp.py", line 200, in get_font
    font = self.get_font(None, subspec)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pdfminer2-20151206-py2.7.egg/pdfminer/pdfinterp.py", line 191, in get_font
    font = PDFCIDFont(self, spec)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pdfminer2-20151206-py2.7.egg/pdfminer/pdffont.py", line 643, in __init__
    self.cidcoding = '%s-%s' % (self.cidsysteminfo.get('Registry', b'unknown').decode("latin1"),
AttributeError: 'PDFObjRef' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Any insights are appreciated!